# Validity of ideal gas law for pure species or mixture

Tags: water, gas-laws, pressure, ideal-gas, nitrogen

I'm currently dealing with an application involving gases. I have pure nitrogen as a pressurizer and eventually water vapour (only if condition for evaporation or boiling are met).
I wanted to ask to which extent can I consider pure species or mixture as ideal gases. I know that nitrogen reaches critical condition when pressure is about 33 bar. My application would have initially a small amount of nitrogen pressurized at 17 bar approximately.
Is it better to switch to a cubic equation of state like the Peng - Robinson one? Would that justify the additional complexity with respect to the ideal case?

Comment: Why won't you calculate a few points both ways and see how big the difference is?

Comment: Yep @Ivan Neretin, I'm structuring the code for computation in the ideal case for which computation is straight but dealing with real gas has to consider another level of complexity if dealing with different equation. I will try as you suggested ;)

Comment: Nitrogen  crit. conditions are  -147 deg C + 34 atm.

Comment: Thanks @Poutnik, i think i won't exceed over the critical range since nitrogen will remain in gaseous state.

Comment: At room temp. you'd have to go *much* further than 34 atm. for N2 to be something different than just a compressed gas. Than again a compressed gas isn't necessarily all that ideal. Maybe start with van der Waals.